# Query Kendo UI DataSource

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I want to use the DataSource as a local DB where by I can query certain data. I tried the following:

```
this.get("productsSource").query({
    filter: { field: "dirty", operator: "eq", value: true} 
});
var dirty = this.get("productsSource").view();
```

This works great. However, the Drop Down List bound to this DataSource is now showing only the "dirty" records. As if the query affected the entire DataSource.

What I am after is to just return certain records based on a filter criteria without changing the "view" of the DataSource.

Is that doable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how it's designed; a simple solution for your scenario would be to create a new DS which creates a copy of the data, then query that:

```
var originalDS = this.get("productsSource");
var filterDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: originalDS.data() });
var dirty = filterDS.query({
    filter: { field: "dirty", operator: "eq", value: true} 
}).view();
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Creating a deep copy using jquery.

Comment: Minor bug, you can't call "view()" on a "query()". First call the query method then view (on filterDS).